Are sun dried/oven dried Tomatoes considered cooked?
I googled this question and it says:

sun-dried tomatoes are not cooked, but rather dehydrated:
Dehydration process Sun-dried tomatoes are made by removing water from
tomatoes through dehydration in the sun, a dehydrator, or an oven”

When I understand exposure to the sun will dry and not cook tomatoes, all the recipes I found on oven based sun dried tomatoes mentioned leaving them at 250 degrees (I’m Assuming Fahrenheit which is 123 Celsius).
Surely this is hot enough to consider something to be cooked - I mean boiling is 100c so of it’s at that temperature why wouldn’t it be cooked over a few hours.
Or is it the boiling, roasting at even higher temperatures etc chemically changed the tomatoes far more making them
considered to be cooked?
Also what is the criteria here for something to be cooked which means sun drying through the oven is not considered cooked?

Can you please clarify what the underlying question is? Is it the definition of the term “cooked” (very hard to define, and certainly not only via temperature)? Something else?

Along with Stephie's question, are you asking about recipes people have written for replicating sun-dried tomatoes at home (which may use methods other than sun-drying), or actual sun-dried tomatoes that are, well, dried in the sun?

None of the rather extensive scientific literature on drying tomatoes suggests anything higher than 70°C and the majority of studies that have trialed that high don't recommend it. 35-45°C is much more commonly recommended. And simply doing a search without limiting it to reliable sources I still find "as low as your oven will go" far more than "250 degrees"
